# Как правильно настроить security config при использовании Spring Boot версии 3.2.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Пытаюсь разобраться с SpringSecurity.

Написал простой конфиг, в котором есть такой бин:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/home").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll())
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .formLogin(login -> login
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
            );
    return http.build();
}
```

Написал контроллер, который должен обеспечивать аутентификацию:

```
   @Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private final SecurityService securityService;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLoginPage(){
        return "login.html";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> auth(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password){
        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password);
        AuthResponse authResponse = securityService.authenticateUser(loginRequest);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authResponse);
    }

}
```

Написал контроллер, который должен возвращать страницу, к которой имеют доступ только аутентифицированные пользователи:

```
@Controller
public class MainPageController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String getMainPage(){
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

Для теста написал html страницу, с которой должен вызываться метод POST/login:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <title>Авторизация</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Авторизация</h2>
<form action="/login" method="post">
  <label for="username">Логин:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br><br>

  <label for="password">Пароль:</label>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" required><br><br>

  <button type="submit">Войти</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

По моей задумке, в результате выполнения данного метода, в случае успешной аутентификации должен возвращаться объект следующего класса:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class AuthResponse {

    private String email;
    private String token;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String patronymic;
    private List<String> roles;
}
```

Но вместо этого сейчас, при успешной аутентификации я вижу во вкладке Network браузера, что метод POST/login возвращает статус 302 Found и Type document / Redirect, после чего меня перебрасывает на страницу /home

Когда вызываю данный метод через Postman, тоже получаю в ответ html страницу /home
В чем может быть причина, как правильно настроить конфиг, чтобы в ответ получать json с данными пользователя, в том числе jwt, для дальнейшей передаче в заголовке

Comment: Попробуйте в цепочке настроек Security установить в `.loginProcessingUrl()` у `login` какое-нибудь значение, отличное от `/login`. Например, `/login-processing`.

Comment: @Byb когда делаю так, получаю ошибку 405 Method not allowed, в терминале Idea вижу:
2024-03-07T11:39:13.883+03:00  WARN 20304 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported]

Comment: Вру - такая ошибка была из за того, что я не поменял action на форме логина. Теперь я сделал чтобы с формы логина уходил запрос на POST/login-user и в .loginProcessingUrl() тоже пописал "/login-user", но стало работать также, как было до этого - возвращается html страница, вместо JSON-объекта

Comment: Я имел в виду, чтобы тот эндпоинт, на который вы посылаете `username` и `password`, отличался от того, который использует Spring. Если у вас на выдачу страницы стоит `/login`, то и обработку аутентификации он скорее всего делает по `/login`, только на метод `POST`. А раз так, то, возможно, его стандартные действия перекрывают ваши, и поэтому он сам логинит пользователя и возвращает страницу. Скорее всего это неправда, но можете попробовать.